# What happens to Talia's truck driver in Batman - The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

At the climax of *The Dark Knight Rises*:

> Talia is in a truck that carries the bomb, Batman is in the Bat, Selina Kyle is driving the Batpod, and there's a couple of tumbler-tanks around there. Batman is trying to lead the truck to where Lucius Fox is, to put the bomb back in place and disengage it. Thalia stubbornly refuses to let them do so.

so then:

> There's a lot of gunfire coming from the bat. Talia tells the truck driver, next to her, to stay put. More gunfire and explosions everywhere, then something happens to the driver and Talia takes the wheel but the truck falls down on a bridge. When Gordon checks the cockpit Talia is there, but there's no trace of the driver.

We know that Batman (who doesn't seem to like fire-arms except for those present in all his vehicles) doesn't kill (Nolan's Batman explicitly did and said so in the two previous movies of the saga).

Could somebody clarify what happens to the truck driver during those scenes?

Comment: Please note that while Batman does not like fire-arms, the vehicles shown in the series are not developed purely for Batman, but instead for use by the military, who do not share batman's distaste for firearms.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. I just wanted to address that Batman was using firepower against the truck, and that is less likely to be able to control the amount of damage that you could do to people with that.

Comment: Related: [Batman vs the truck driver, please explain](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36016/49)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [film's screenplay](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uwV8rddtKRgC&pg=PA502&lpg=PA502&dq=%22Bullets%20fly%20through%20the%20cab%22&source=bl&ots=0xkD4fxZ1F&sig=FERzMP8JR1cEZBXb3kemnhmnQko&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) indicates that he died, a victim of Batman's gunfire.

> INT. CAB, BLACK TRUCK – CONTINUOUS 290
>
> **Bullets fly through the cab. The driver takes one, falls forward,
>   dead.** Talia takes the wheel – bullets keep coming.

Interestingly, the [film's novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13536475-the-dark-knight-rises) disagrees somewhat, attributing his death to a random piece of concrete flicked into the cab (by a bullet or a rocket)

> The Bat came in for another run. It blasted the road in front of them,
>   forcing the truck to veer right at an intersection. Smoke and flames
>   burst from the flying debris. **Against all odds, a random chunk of
>   concrete smashed through the driver’s side window, striking the man in
>   the head. He jerked, then slumped forward onto the wheel, blood
>   leaking from a fractured skull.**

Either way, his body was "shoved aside" when Talia took over driving, presumably it's just pushed back into the rear seats (out of sight) when the truck crashes.

> The truck careened out of control.
>
> **Talia shoved the man’s body aside** and took hold of the wheel. She
>   steered the truck back into the center of the lane. Out of the corner
>   of her eye, she glimpsed the Bat banking off into the sky, no doubt
>   preparing for another assault.

Answer (score 15):

The driver dies around 3:05 or so. It looks like she pushes him out of the truck or at least out of the way (and out of sight) at around 3:14-3:16.

Either that, or he [became one with the force](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoBodyLeftBehind) (TVTropes).

Comment: He collapses at 3:09/3:10 and she pushes him out at 3:15 (kinda off-screen but it's suggested by her movement right before the cut since she's now sitting in the middle). It's interesting to note that I don't see any visible damage on the vehicle though, so the bullets probably warped right through the glass/armor. :P

Comment: Thank you both. Thanks @Mario for pointing out that there is no visible damage on the cockpit, so we can also assume that the driver faints/collapses due to a concussion or something, instead of just being killed by Batman's gunfire.

Comment: @Deion Batman is a stormtrooper?

Comment: @calccrypto, I don't know. I'm just happy to know that he didn't become both an _executioner_ and a hypocrite just at the very end of this trilogy.

Comment: She doesn't open the door so he couldn't have been pushed out of the truck

Answer (score 4):

He perishes after a missile launched from the Bat explodes in front of the truck (yes Batman kills him, indirectly if you will)

[image: Dead drivahh]

He is then tossed aside by Thalia so that she may regain control of the vehicle but never gets kicked out from the truck until later when it crashes. The door opens and the guy's corpse gets ejected.

[image: They see him rollin']

I know it's a common trope that the bad guy always gets rid off his fallen goons' corpses, showing their lack of empathy and camaraderie that the protagonists always have, but it didn't happen in this scenario which is good and consistent to how these League of Shadow members were portrayed treating each other during the movie ("brother", "friend", etc)

Answer (score 0):

I actually thought that from the missiles fired at them made something on the inside explode thus killing the driver. Also you can sort of see the body flying out of the truck when it falls off the ramp for a split second.

Comment: Did you mean to comment or to answer?

Answer (score 0):

The driver is clearly struck by a stray round from the Bat.  Assuming the weapon is a large caliber (.50 cal or 20mm), it is unlikely he could survive an impact from such a round.  They are very powerful and leave a very large wound. Also, when the truck hits the lower street after falling off the overpass, the driver can be seen falling out of the cab and ending up close to the rear wheels, possibly getting run over.  When Gordon climbs out of the back he looks down at the driver.  So, Batman did kill him, but at the very least, it was not truly intentional, but Batman was trying to stop that truck, and the driver dying was collateral damage.

Comment: Do you have any evidence?